# Looking for a portable color picker (from anywhere on the PC screen)

Tags: windows, html, portable

I'm looking for a way to find the HTML color code (HEX) for any image or point on the PC screen.

For example, while viewing a web page, I sometimes require finding the HTML color of a certain point on the web page. Is it possible to open this utility from the system tray, and then pick the color of any point on the screen?

I know about Google Chrome extensions that would allow me to do this, but I was looking for a way to just pick a color of anything visible on the screen! Web pages, photographs, desktop icons, etc etc....

I'm currently using Photoshop for this, and it takes a lot of time to load, due to which I thought I'll ask here instead.

I'm using Win7 64bit Dell XPS Laptop, with Chrome Browser.

Comment: Had the same requirements, that's why i developed [colorbug](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/colorbug/colorbug.html). There is a portable version available, the only requirement is an installed DotNet 2.0 which is part of Windows for a long time.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: Hi! Would it be possible for you to create a notepad++ color picker too? I found [this color picker](https://pscolorpicker.codeplex.com/) on codeplex, and since I don't know how to create plugins etc, I couldn't add it as a colorpicker to notepad++...

Comment: @mk177 - Why wold you need it to be part of notepad++, is it because you would insert the selected color directly into the text?

Comment: Well... Not entirely due to that... The utility downloaded from that code plex page, is actually a c# form on which you click a button and THEN the color picker is displayed.... I was hoping for a direct exe file to the color picker..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Colour Contrast Analyser](http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastAnalyser) can do this (and a lot more).

It was specifically designed as a developer's contrast testing tool, allowing you to enter or pick from the screen two different colours and it will tell you the contrast difference between the two.

It is also very lightweight and fast, enough that it can be used as a simple colour picker, and I use it for this very purpose quite often.

It can also show the output in RGB if you need it, and you can set it to grab the colour of a  single pixel, or give the calculated average colour of a square up to 8x8 pixels in size.

The only negative I can say for CCA is that if you have more than one monitor it won't work on any but the primary display, as it just keeps showing the last colour seen on the primary monitor whenever you move into the secondary display.

Comment: Thankyou winterblood! Couldn't understand how to pic the color in the app, but after a few minutes, found the color picker beside each HEX value in foreground/background rows.... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I like [Color Selector](http://colorselector.sourceforge.net/). It's free and very small (68 KB).

You can also use a simple Html-Document with this line:

```
<input type="color" onchange="document.getElementById('c').value = this.value"/><input id="c"/>
```

... but this seems to be a big buggy. At least with Google Chrome.

Comment: Thankyou Werner... I read your answer AFTER accepting winterblood's answer. This tool could be useful too, but the `Color Contrast Analyzer` has zoom functionality for the picker, where it zooms while picking the color. I only found a crosshair in the `Color Selector` ... Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

[Color Seizer](http://www.alexnolan.net/software/colorseizer.htm) is a developer's colour picker that displays colours from the screen in a number of different output formats including HTML colour codes, RGB, HSL and a few other language-specific formats.

It is small and fast, but the user interface is a little anti-intuitive (at least for me). However, it does have the added benefit of working correctly in a multi-monitor configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across [Instant EyeDropper](http://instant-eyedropper.com/) minutes ago, a great pick. 
500 Kbs, free, extracts the color into several different codifications, and automatically copies the color code to the clipboard.

Simply install, launch, click its icon in the icons tray, hold the mouse button, and start hovering all over the screen, while getting every pixel's color definition (in the codification you choose with a mouse right click).